# How to use foreach inside html

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@item.Name" placeholder="Search here" style="width: 450px; height: 40px">
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">
                                                                                                <i class="dripicons-search"></i>
                                                                                            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
        @*
        <div class="form-group">
          <input class="form-control " id="myInput " type="text" placeholder="Search.. " style="width: 350px; height: 30px " />
          <button type="button" class="btn-icons btn-inverse-secondary " id="data-member-editbtn-id " data-member-id="@@item.Id ">
                                                                                                <div class="col-sm-11 "><i class="dripicons-search "></i></div>
                                                                                            </button>
        </div>*@
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>@item.Name</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" checked="@item.IsActive"></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-icons btn-inverse-secondary" id="data-editbtn-id" data-id="@item.Id"><div><i class="icon-pencil"></i></div></button></td>
      <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-icons btn-inverse-secondary" id="data-delete-id" data-id="@item.Id"><div><i class="dripicons-trash"></i></div></button></td>
      <td></td>

    </tr>

}
```

I'm trying to loop the table using data in MySQL and every time when I run the program this error pops up.
Is it because I'm using 2 `<tr>`?
can anyone help me out?
[image]

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(new CustomerProfileEventsService().Select(SelectType.All));
        }
```

Comment: Object ref is a Razor message, so your Razor syntax is correct - it means `Model` is null - you're not setting this in your Action (or not passing it correctly) which you've not included in the question.  Include your Action's `return` statement in the question.

Comment: @freedomn-m done, just added the code

Comment: Add you can assert that `new CustomerProfileEventsService().Select(SelectType.All)` is not null?